# what will be the equivalent of postgresql \m for Spring Boot JPQL Query, converting native Query to JPQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, jpql

I have requirement to write a spring boot JPQL query. I have a raw Postgres query. But I can't find the equivalent for \m for JPQL

The query is this:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where  title ~* '(\mbag\M)| (\msamsung\M)';
```

Comment: I don't think JPQL has any support for regular expressions

Comment: So, is there any other approach that i should follow to achieve this, other than regular expresssions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985205/does-eclipselink-support-queries-containing-regular-expression